# Legos falling into place and stacking up. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Tags: animation, particles, physics

I am making an animation to be projected onto a wall at a theater. I need to make legos fall from the top of the screen and land stacking up to form a wall. After that I will have the Legos movie logo crash through the wall of legos at the end.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?I tried using the particle emitter to let a bunch of legos fall randomly into place, but I was thinking it would look much nicer if they fell on top of one another forming a wall rather than just a bunch of pieces.

I've been trying different things out with little success. If you were given this project how would you go about doing it? I am a bit stuck right now trying to figure this out.

Comment: Shoot it in reverse and 'upside down' ? Have the bricks fall off the wall, potentially with some keyed animation or guidance by unseen obstacles soon after falling for more control....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make an animation of mesh pieces assembling (something like an explode modifier in reverse)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123588/how-can-i-make-an-animation-of-mesh-pieces-assembling-something-like-an-explode)

Comment: May want to look at Duarte Ramos' Answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/random-sized-cylinders-with-no-intersection-gaps) for a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can just revert the physic animation. Then for the logo crashing make another shot with the same wall at the begging and put both together.

Answer (score 0):

i made a small file for you  [click here to download](http://www.nm-8.com/stack/falllinglego.blend)
i would use dupliverts on a distorted plane. the 4 distortion modifiers use a blend texture in several progressions, and are controlled by animated empties. this way the mesh gets to rest in the end. 
its tricky to aniamte the plane using the empties, so that it looks accurate, but its surely much more straight forward than setting up a particle simulation, or even animation nodes.